# Nodejs mysql asynchronous calling (waiting for the DB query to be over)

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have an issue I want my code to complete the db query and then proceed to next commands, how do I make it happen, the only solutions I found was using promise, async and await. I could not find any way to integrate them. Please use this code and show me the necessary changes and where I should incorporate them.

The code is as follows:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

console.log("in the db1")

  let gh="select * from table1"
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'db1'
  })

  connection.query(gh, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log('Connection Successful')
    connection.end();
  })
console.log("in the db2")
```

The output which I am getting is :

```
in the db1
in the db2
Connection Successful
```

I just want the code to wait for the DB query to be completed and then proceed to next step so i can in future manipulate DB query results accordingly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The query method is asynchronous, therefore you can't expect the flow to wait for it to be over.

The most basic approach would be to follow your flow inside the callback

```
console.log("before query1");

connection.query(query1, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log("after query1");
});
```

But this could lead to a callback nightmare if you want to make subsequest queries:

```
connection.query(query1, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log("after query1", {results,fields});

    connection.query(query2, function (error2, results2, fields2) {
       console.log("after query2", {results2,fields2});

       connection.query(query3, function (error3, results3, fields3) {
          console.log("after query3, {results3,fields3}");
       });
    });
});
```

If you switch to a promise based approach you could encapsulate each call to `connection.query` to return a promise such as:

```
  const mysql = require('mysql-promise'),
    connection = mysql.createConnection({...});

  connection.connect();

  async function queryAsync(sentence) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(sentence, function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve( results);
      });
    });
  }
```

And then:

```
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      return queryAsync(sentence1);
    })
    .then(results1 => {
      console.log('after query 1',  results1);
      return queryAsync(sentence2);
    })
    .then(results2 => {
      console.log('after query 2',  results2);
      return queryAsync(sentence3);
    })
    .then(results3 => {
      console.log('after query 3',  results3);
      connection.end();
      return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      connection.end();
      return;
    });
```

Or, using async/await

```
  Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
    try {
      let  results1 = await queryAsync(sentence1);
      console.log('after query1',  results1);

      let  results2 = await queryAsync(sentence2);
      console.log('after query2',  results2);

      let  results3 = await queryAsync(sentence3);
      console.log('after query3',  results3);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    connection.end();

    return;
  });
```

---

#### There's already a library that does the above for you

Anyway, there's already a wrapper library [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) that does the promise wrapping job for you:

```
# Promise approach
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

mysql
    .createConnection({...})
    .then(connection => {
      return connection.query(sentence1);
    })
    .then(results1=>{...})
    .catch(err=>{...});
```

Or
     # Async/await approach
     const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

```
 mysql
    .createConnection({...})
    .then(async connection => {
      try {
      let  results1 = await connection.query(sentence1);
      console.log('after query1',  results1);
      ...
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      return connection.end();
  });
```

Try it on <kbd>[RunKit](https://runkit.com/ffflabs/mysql-promise/2.0.0)</kbd>

**Sidenote**

BTW: You don't need to start with `Promise.resolve()` to wrap everything in an async function. I just think

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(()=> {
     …
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Is easier to understand than

```
(async () => {
    …
})().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I tried all the listed ways above none of them worked, please could you clarify with a working code or could you modify my mentioned code as I tried still the commands below db is getting executed and is not waiting for DB query to be completed.

Comment: The problem statement which i have is i need to do a callback with the results of the db query. The callback still executes in the above code with the undefined value of the variable as db query. I want the callback to return a value which it gets after executing the query(The value is the first name)

Comment: If you don't pass a callback to query method and instead **await** it, `var results = await db.query(/*.. no callback../*)` it will be stored in the variable `results`. The in the next line you can call `cb(null, results)`